# Query to update an array field by using another array field of same document in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, mongodb-query

## Scenario

I've the following document from `Chat` collection with an array of `messages` and `members` in the chat.

And for each message, there will be status field which will store the **delivered and read** timestamp with respect to users.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60679797b4365465745065b2"),
    "members" : [ 
        ObjectId("604e02033f4fc07b6b82771c"), 
        ObjectId("6056ef4630d7b103d8043abd"), 
        ObjectId("6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79c")
    ],
    "isGroup" : true,
    "createdAt" : 1617401743720.0,
    "updatedAt" : 1617436504453.0,
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "createdAt" : 1617401743719.0,
            "updatedAt" : 1617401743719.0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("60679797b4365465745065b3"),
            "body" : "This is test message",
            "senderId" : ObjectId("6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79c"),
            "status" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I want to insert the following data, into `messages.status` array, to know when the message is received/read by the member.

```
{
    receiverId: <member of chat>
    deliveredAt: <timestamp>
    readAt: <timestamp>
}
```

## Question

How to **write a query** to insert the above json for each member (except the sender) in the `status` array by using the data from existing field?

So that, after query, the document should look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60679797b4365465745065b2"),
    "members" : [ 
        ObjectId("604e02033f4fc07b6b82771c"), 
        ObjectId("6056ef4630d7b103d8043abd"), 
        ObjectId("6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79c")
    ],
    "isGroup" : true,
    "createdAt" : 1617401743720.0,
    "updatedAt" : 1617436504453.0,
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "createdAt" : 1617401743719.0,
            "updatedAt" : 1617401743719.0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("60679797b4365465745065b3"),
            "body" : "This is test message",
            "senderId" : ObjectId("6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79c"),
            "status" : [{
                "receiverId": ObjectId("604e02033f4fc07b6b82771c")
                "deliveredAt": <timestamp>
                "readAt": <timestamp>
            }, {
                "receiverId": ObjectId("6056ef4630d7b103d8043abd")
                "deliveredAt": <timestamp>
                "readAt": <timestamp>
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Edit

I'm able to do this for static data.

Link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LgVPfRoXL5p

For easy understanding: I've to map the `members` array and insert it into the `status` field of the `messages`

**MongoDB Version:** 4.0.5

Comment: Hi Can you elaborate on this point _" insert the above json for each member (except the sender)"_. Like how do you identify the sender in `chats` collection?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator to define custom functions to implement behavior not supported by the MongoDB Query Language. So along with [updates-with-aggregate-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) and `$function` you can update `messages.status` array with only receiver's details as shown below:

**NOTE**: Works only with MongoDB version >= 4.4.

Try this:

```js
let messageId = ObjectId("60679797b4365465745065b3");

db.chats.update(
  { "messages._id": messageId },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        "messages": {
          $map: {
            input: "$messages",
            as: "message",
            in: {
              $cond: {
                if: { $eq: ["$$message._id", messageId] },
                then: {
                  $function: {
                    body: function (message, members) {
                      message.status = [];
                      for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
                        if (message.senderId.valueOf() != members[i].valueOf()) {
                          message.status.push({
                            receiverId: members[i],
                            deliveredAt: new Date().getTime(),
                            readAt: new Date().getTime()
                          })
                        }
                      }

                      return message;
                    },
                    args: ["$$message", "$members"],
                    lang: "js"
                  }
                },
                else: "$$message"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60679797b4365465745065b2"),
    "members" : [
        ObjectId("604e02033f4fc07b6b82771c"),
        ObjectId("6056ef4630d7b103d8043abd"),
        ObjectId("6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79c")
    ],
    "isGroup" : true,
    "createdAt" : 1617401743720,
    "updatedAt" : 1617436504453,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60679797b4365465745065b3"),
            "createdAt" : 1617401743719,
            "updatedAt" : 1617401743719,
            "body" : "This is test message",
            "senderId" : ObjectId("6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79c"),
            "status" : [
                {
                    "receiverId" : ObjectId("604e02033f4fc07b6b82771c"),
                    "deliveredAt" : 1617625735318,
                    "readAt" : 1617625735318
                },
                {
                    "receiverId" : ObjectId("6056ef4630d7b103d8043abd"),
                    "deliveredAt" : 1617625735318,
                    "readAt" : 1617625735318
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60679797b4365465745065b4"),
            "createdAt" : 1617401743719,
            "updatedAt" : 1617401743719,
            "body" : "This is test message",
            "senderId" : ObjectId("6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79d"),
            "status" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It'll work but I want to execute it for each member of the chat and what if it has 100 members?

Comment: No, I mean I just want to map the `members` array and insert it in the `status`. Did this make the question clear to you?

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: Mongodb version is 4.0.5

Comment: Check the updated answer, If you upgrade your MongoDB.

Comment: Sure, will let  you know

Answer (score 0):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/FoOvxXp6nji

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

> The filtered positional operator $[] identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update operation, e.g.

```
db.collection.update({
  "messages.senderId": "6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79c" // query 
},
{
  "$push": {
    "messages.$[m].status": [ // push into the matching element of arrayFilters
      {
        "receiverId": ObjectId("604e02033f4fc07b6b82771c")
      },
      {
        "receiverId": ObjectId("6056ef4630d7b103d8043abd")
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "m.senderId": "6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79c" // matches array element where senderId is 6031e3dce8934f11f8c9a79c
    }
  ]
})
```

---

Note- add index to `messages.senderId` for performance

Comment: I'm able to do this without `$[]`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/LgVPfRoXL5p. Just need to map the status array directly from `members` field. That's where I'm stuck. One way is to get the members first then map it on the server side then insert it in the db. But could this be done in one query?